# Добавить атрибут через JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код который создаёт кнопку которая открывает проводник на гаджете пользователя. Сейчас мне понадобилось добавить к этой кнопке атрибут multiple, но не знаю как это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

```
{
    key: "createFileButton",
    value: function() {
        var t = this,
        e = g("div", [this.CSS.button])
        return e.innerHTML = this.config.buttonContent || "".concat(h.a, " Выберите несколько изображений "),  e.addEventListener("click", function() {
            t.onSelectFile()
        }), e
    }
}
```

Comment: `e.setAttribute`, скорее всего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    key: "createFileButton",
    value: function() {
        var t = this,
        e = g("div", [this.CSS.button])
        e.setAttribute(имяАтрибута, значение);
        return e.innerHTML = this.config.buttonContent || "".concat(h.a, " Выберите несколько изображений "),  e.addEventListener("click", function() {
            t.onSelectFile()
        }), e
    }
}
```